# Custom HTML tag CSS :nth-of-type counting IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

I ran into a very weird issue with the CSS selector :nth-of-type in IE. It seems that the counter in :nth-of-type counts +1 on custom tags, like this example:

```html
<div>
  <home>Tester 1</home>
  <home>Tester 2</home>
  <home>Tester 3</home>
  <home>Tester 4</home>
</div>
```

If I want to select the first `<home>` tag, I would have to do this:

```js
document.querySelector("home:nth-of-type(2)");
```

and the second:

```
document.querySelector("home:nth-of-type(3)");
```

Could anyone please tell me why this happens? Are there some kind of documentation of this or something?

Comment: How about nth-child? Same results?

Comment: No that actually don't work at all.

Comment: Have you checked via dev tools what DOM structure IE creates from those “custom tags”? IE does not support _proper_ implementation of custom elements yet; so to it those are mostly just “unknown tags”, and how it treats them might be unpredictably.

Comment: @CBroe Okay so what you are saying is that this is a issue you can't rely on with this solution? So I can't rely on the home:nth-of-type(2) always will give me the first element of that type?

Comment: No, that is not at all what I am saying. What I am saying is that IE might not handle your “custom elements” the way you think it does - and using dev tools to see what _actual_ DOM it created would be a first step in debugging this issue.

Comment: Also of note here: Did you simply write `<home>` in your HTML or did you actually add some functionality (behaviours)

Comment: nth-of-type(2) actually refers to the second occurance. never seen a home tag, but well, doubt that'd interfere with the nth-of-type rule.bear in mind that ie has poor support for standards, in particular exotic stuff like nth-of-type -- at least anything pre-10 releases. ymmv

Comment: The <home> tag is a custom tag and thats why I have these issues. Because with all default tags the :nth-of-type will work fine.

But I have tested it on a lot of computers and different versions of IE and it seems to be solving the issue, that I just count +1 with the :nth-of-type.

Comment: All this talk of "custom tags" and "default tags" makes me think that you believe it's all right to just insert homebrewn tag names into HTML. It isn't. The only made-up names that are safe are names containing at least one dash. If you really want to make your own tags, use XML.